# How to redirect to a different url using tr onlick

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I have this Razor page Userview which includes a list of students in a table

I want on clicking a row to open a URL passing the ID of selected student row. Here's what I got so far

```
@foreach (var student in Model._User.Students)
        {
            <tr onclick="location.href = '@(Url.Action("Info", new { id = student.Id }))'">
                <td>Some basic info of student</td>
            </tr>
        }
```

I expect to get redirected to /Info/{id} but instead got /Useview/{id}?action=Info

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Url.Page` :

```
<tr onclick="location.href = '@(Url.Page("Info", new { id = 1 }))'">
```

Then if you have another page named `Info` , you can get the parameter :

```
@page "{id}"
@model RAZOR.Pages.InfoModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Info";
}

<p>The Id is @Model.Id</p>
```

Info.cshtml.cs:

```
public class InfoModel : PageModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public void OnGet(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}
```